# Logitech G29 on the PS3

Tags: ps3

I am considering buying a Logitech G29 racing wheel.

It's a great wheel but unfortunately, the stick shift does not work on the PS3.

I want my steering wheel to be universal, in other words, to play in all PS3, PS4, PC.
Otherwise, for me, there is no point investing money in a steering wheel if it does not work across all platforms.

So is there a way to make this fully playable on the PS3?

I have seen some converters on ebay, [like this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/PS3-PS4-XBOX-360-One-NS-Switch-Console-Converter-Adapter-to-Logitech-G25-G27-G29/143069368523?epid=23027474130&hash=item214f9950cb:g:aPgAAOSwQZdcJgQZ)

Do these things work 100%, like a G29 on the PS3?